# What is the maximum file size which i can upload to azure blob uploadfile method

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Please can i know what the maximum file size to upload to the azure storage blob using uploadfile api.

Comment: Note `CloudBlob.UploadFile` is from the old 1.7 lib and is deprecated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Block Blobs originally had a maximum size of 200GB (with 4MB block size), and now may be up to 4.77TB (with new 100MB block size). Maximum number of blocks per blob: 50,000.

Take a look at [operations on Block Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-block-blobs) for more information about the REST API calls (including `Put Block` and `Put Block List`)

Comment: The max size was increased a while back right? :) It's now max 50,000 blocks with 100 MB each (around 4.75 TB).

Comment: Correct, though the SDK has been changed over the years. I'll double-check the method names etc and update the answer accordingly. Thanks for catching the old storage size.

Answer (score 9):

Update: as of December 2016 the maximum size of a Block Blob has increased to roughly 4.75TB (50,000 x 100MB blocks).

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/general-availability-larger-block-blobs-in-azure-storage/

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on what type of blob you are using. [Understanding Block Blobs and Page Blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx) explains everything in detail.

If you are using block blobs (UploadFile API):

> If you are writing a block blob that is no more than 64 MB in size, you can upload it in its entirety with a single write operation. (Storage clients default to 32 MB, settable using the SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes property.)

Comment: I believe the quote you were looking for was the one just before the one which was pasted. "Each block can be a different size, up to a maximum of 4 MB. The maximum size for a block blob is 200 GB, and a block blob can include no more than 50,000 blocks"

Answer (score 0):

Over time, the maximum upload size has increased.  According to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from 2021, the Maximum blob size (via Put Block List) is approximately 190.7 TiB (4000 MiB X 50,000 blocks) for Version 2019-12-12 and later.  The referenced doc gives size limits for other versions as well.