# Understanding Azure Block Blob Storage Limitations

Tags: azure

I am a bit confused on how block blob storage works so I bit confused on how the limitations work(from what I read that most people will not get even close to the limitations but I still like to understand how it's been applied). I been reading [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction)

The limitations seem to be like this

> Block blobs store text and binary data, up to about 4.7 TB. Block
>   blobs are made up of blocks of data that can be managed individually.
>
> Azure Blob storage limits Resource    Target Max size of single blob
>   container Same as max storage account capacity Max number of blocks in
>   a block blob or append blob   50,000 blocks Max size of a block in a
>   block blob

[image]

I understand the above picture but I don't understand in the above image what is actually the "block blob".

I don't understand if I store say all my pictures in 1 container will I be reaching the limit?

Say if I had something super crazy like I have in this picture container 10 million photos each photo is 100mb, would I have gone over the limit?

or does block blob mean if I had img001 and it was 1gb it would get separated into blocks and the limit would be 50,000 blocks?

Then img002 would have it's own 50,000 block limit and so forth(ie the limits for storage are against each image not the total container size)

Comment: Not quite sure of your question but... the number of objects storable is "infinite" (well, up to the storage account size limit)

Comment: FYI I answered this a few years ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545953/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-files-that-can-be-stored-in-an-azure-blob-stor/32546038#32546038), regarding blob counts...

Comment: Also FYI I answered another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129125/2721090), regarding maximum blob size, based on block size and number of blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The 50000 blocks limit is for each object in container.  You can have multiple objects each having 50000*100mb  size.

Normally you don't hit these limits. At least I have never been able to hit them. :-)

You can find more information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs.